# Combining C# with C++ in a single project

Tags: c#, c++

I am assigned a project in which there are two parts :

1. Database Programming
2. Game Programming

I am incharge of Database programming and my partner the later. But I am friendly with C-sharp Database programming as it is very efficient using Visual Studio. But he has a Game experience in C++.

Our target system is Windows 7,database will be Sql Server Database, and game can be in C or C++.
We will have a link in Windows forms that starts the Game.

How do we solve this problem without changing our partners?

Comment: You can create winforms in C++ (but you have to us a GUI library).

Comment: @TonyTheTiger: In order to use WinForms with C++, you need to use C++/CLI. WinForms *is* the GUI library.

Comment: @Cody Gray : Person is familiar with C

Comment: @Cody yes, you're right, I was merely thinking of WinForms as just a general window in windows, and there's several libs that you can use to create that. But yea, technically WinForms is the GUI lib. Got it mixed up I guess

Comment: I thought you said they were familiar with C++. Which is it?

Comment: "How do we solve this problem without changing our partners?" What *is* your problem?

Answer (score 2):

From a technical point of view it is possible to write a project in multiple languages. From a practical standpoint it is not a good idea.
If this is a small project that will not be enhanced and will be write once and forget then it is fine, otherwise not.
You don't necessarily need to change partners, one of you just needs to step up and say they will jump the learning curve. As a programmer you need to be able to work in whatever language is required.
There are many factors that decide which language/library to use. Write them down with the pros and cons and decide which makes the most sense for your application. Agree that once this is settled then the topic will not come back up. Maybe find an neutral arbitrator that you can both elect to decide for you.
A partner is more than their ability to write code in a given language. The coding part is a small part of the project.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest looking at [Managed c++ and the /clr compilation switch for c++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx). Using managed c++ you can expose what you need to the .net world using .net objects where appropriate, but use native c/c++ code internally.

Managed c++ also have alot of ways to integrate efficiently with .net, such as object pinning (no relocation by the gc)

c++ compiled with /clr can be consumed from any .net language like a regular .net assembly. c++ code compiled this way can also consume any .net assembly much like the other .net languages do.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided much details about this game but can't you [`Process.Start`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) the Game from your WinForms application and passing it the necessary parameters that you fetched from the database?

Comment: Sorry for partial information. Our target system is Windows 7! So even if I do Process.Start, C++ executable won't run as it doesnt in Windows 7.....

Comment: @killerCoder, isn't your C++ executable compiled to run on Windows? What is it, a Linux executable?

Comment: @killer: C++ applications run just fine in Windows 7... I develop C++ apps all the time in Windows 7.

Comment: Can u please explain me the procedure? Coz i have to use a DosBox to do my C++ programs. When i try to run the executable, it says it is incompatible with current windows...

Comment: @killerCoder: You mean a DOS box as in a *Console* application? Yes, you can use C++ to develop Console applications, but you can also develop GUI applications that work just like anything you would create in C#.

Comment: @killerCoder, please update your question and provide all the details about your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to wrap the database in a COM object developed in .NET that the game, if written in C++ can consume.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a project right now (and recently completed a similar one) that combined C#, and C++ libraries using C++/CLI. The data collection and signal processing were all written in C++ (your game piece) and the forms, xml and plotting was all done in C# (your db piece). C++/CLI handled the impedance mismatch between the two languages. I actually ended up writing little more than a mediator class in C++/CLI (I find it much more pleasant to write in C#).  I think this would work for you too. The only issue is that C++/CLI is not C++. In fact I would suggest that the C# programmer learn C++/CLI rather than the C++ programmer. My reasoning is that syntactical differences between the languages are rather trivial and the C# programmer can probably learn those faster than the the C++ programmer coming to grips to what managed code and .NET is all about. That said, if you both took responsibility for the C++/CLI piece you would have all the skill sets needed to tackle it with the minimum amount of pain.